# Is it "King of the Jews" or "King of the Judeans?"

Tags: cross

Matthew 27:37 says this was written on the cross, "THIS IS JESUS, THE KING OF THE JEWS." There is a lot of prejudice toward the word 'Jew.' I would like to know if the oldest bibles actually said "Jews" or "Judeans." Thank you in advance.

"When they had crucified him, they divided up his clothes by casting lots. And sitting down, they kept watch over him there. Above his head, they placed the written charge against him: THIS IS JESUS. THE KING OF THE JEWS."

Comment: [Identity of "the Jews" in John's gospel](//hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/25725)

Comment: See this- a chart regarding the Pilate inscription.

http://www.christiananswers.net/q-aig/aig-t001.html

Comment: Judeans. As someone shared with you earlier, the word Jew did not exist.

Comment: @Christina, the word Jew *did* exist. "Jew" (or at least its Hebrew equivalent) had been in use as an abbreviation of "Judean" for 800 years before the Crucifixion (e.g. 2 Kings 16:6).

Answer (score 3):

Someone may correct me, but I don't believe that in Greek there is a distinct word for "Judean" as opposed to "Jew": both are conveyed by the word Ἰουδαῖος (*Ioudaios*).  An example of the former meaning would be:

John 3:22 (KJV 1900)

> After these things came Jesus and his disciples into the land of
>   Judaea [lit. "Judean land", ιουδαιαν γην]

Of the former:

John 1:19

> *The Jews* [οι ιουδαιοι] *sent priests and Levites to Jerusalem*

According to witnesses in antiquity, Matthew may have written his Gospel first in Aramaic, but whatever may have been produced has been lost to us.

Comment: This is essentially correct. Both translations ('the Jews' and 'the Judeans') are correct, but tend to imply something different in modern English.

Answer (score 0):

Matthew 27:37 English Standard Version

> And over his head they put the charge against him, which read, “This is Jesus, the King of the **Jews** [G2453].”

Esther 3:6

> But he disdained to lay hands on Mordecai alone. So, as they had made known to him the people of Mordecai, Haman sought to destroy all the **Jews** [G2453], the people of Mordecai, throughout the whole kingdom of Ahasuerus.

However you want to translate G2453, the people group referred to in Matthew 27:37 is the same one in Esther 3:6.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus was a "Judahite" (not a Judean or a Jew). He was born into the original Israelite Kingdom of Judah; He was not born into the later periods, empires, or provinces of Yehud (Persian) or Judea (Roman); nor was He a member of the Pharisees (whom He called "the Jews").

[image]
<sup>**The earliest reference to the Kindom of Judah was in a clay tablet found in Nimrud - the ancient Assyrian capital destroyed this year by ISIS. Shown: The palace in Nimrud.** Credit: M.Chohan, Wikimedia Commons</sup>

> For the sake of good order: The original Israelite kingdom was called **Judah**. During the Persian Period the land became a province of that empire, called **Yehud**; then in the Roman Period, the land became a Roman province called **Judea**. But let us discuss the first of those successive entities. [bold mine]

Source: [Why Are Jews Called Jews?](https://www.haaretz.com/archaeology/2017-02-15/ty-article/why-are-jews-called-jews/0000017f-dbeb-d856-a37f-ffeb3f760000)

Answer (score -3):

Jesus was a Judean, not a Jew. Inhabitants of Judea were called Judeans, not Jews. At that time of Jesus, there was no religious, racial, or national group called Jews in Judea or anywhere in the world. The word Jew did not come into existence until the year 1775. Before that, the word Jew did not exist in any language. The word Jew appeared for the first time in the copy of New Testaments 18th century revisited editions. The religion of Judea at the time of Jesus was Pharisaism. Phariseanism becomes later Talmudism which become Rabbinism, nowadays Judaism. Most of the religious Jewish people today in the world have no heritage to ancient Hebrew or Canaan people or to the land called Israel.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [Tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Comment: The word 'Jews' is used in the [Wycliffe bible of 1382](http://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/40027037).

Comment: Strong's G2453. Ioudaios–Definition: Jewish, a Jew, Judea.

Comment: I wonder where you are getting these "facts" from? The word *did* exist. It is simply a shortened form of "Judean" and was a commonly used word. The first time "Jew", as opposed to "Judean", is used in the Bible is in 2 Kings 16:6, nearly 800 years before the Crucifixion. (And interestingly, at that time the Jews were at war against the Israelites.)